# Show required asmx page instead of directory list

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm developing web service on Visual Studio development server. Browser starts at project root directory and shows files list. I always must select required asmx file to run some tests. Is it possible to ask debugger to show webpage on required asmx address instead of directory list?

Comment: you would need to directly browse to that webservice or right click and make it a startup page (cannot verify if that option is available for asmx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio runs the page that was currently in focus in your designer.

If you set this page, Visual web Developer will start your web site with the Set Page and not the current page in designer.

You can do this by right-click on the page and selecting **Set As Start Page** option from the context menu.

Answer (score 2):

You can set default document on web.config file for specific asmx file name.

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="TestService.asmx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```